# Changing the position of a label when the input is focused using styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm new using styled-components and I been trying to create an input using google material design standards but I haven't been able to recreate the animation that makes the label move when the input is focused.

```
const Input = styled.input`
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`;
const Label = styled.label`
  color: #999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  ${Input}:focus & {
    top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
  }
`;
```

So in resume, I want the label to move 20px up, change its font-size and color when the label is focused, I'm not really sure if my approach is the correct or it will be better just to implement a normal CSS class in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `~` sign to target the label element on input focus

```
const Label = styled.label`
  color: #999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  ${Input}:focus ~ & {
    top:-18px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#5264AE;
  }
`;
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-flower-p39h8)